# How to properly combine 4 bytes to make a float (single)

Tags: c, buffer

I have the following:

```
payload.data[i].data = (buf[8] << 24) | (buf[9] << 16) | (buf[10] << 8) | (buf[11]);
```

note: `payload.data[i].data`if of type float.

Using this: `printf("test:%X%X%X%X", buf[8], buf[9], buf[10], buf[11]);`, I have confirmed that the buffer contains `#42C78A3D` or DEC 99.77 (roughly).

This: `printf("Float value:%f", payload.data[i].data` prints out 1120373248.00, which is DEC for `#42C78A00`

It seems to me that for some reason, `buf[11]` is coming up empty.

Here is a more complete view of my code:

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    struct sensor_payload payload;

    payload.key = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
    payload.id = (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
    payload.type = (buf[4] << 8) | buf[5];
    payload.fields = buf[6];

    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < payload.fields; i++, j = j +33){
        payload.data[i].data_type = buf[j+7];
        payload.data[i].data = (buf[j+8] << 24) | (buf[j+9] << 16) | (buf[j+10] << 8) | (buf[j+11]);
        slog(0, SLOG_DEBUG, "test:%X%X%X%X", buf[8], buf[9], buf[10], buf[11]);
    }

    payload.valid = true;


    return payload;
```

and the definitions:

```
struct sensor_data{
    uint8_t data_type;
    float data;
};

struct sensor_payload{
    uint16_t key, id, type;
    uint8_t fields;
    struct sensor_data data[4];
    bool valid;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot in you code which is unclear. However, the only discrepancy I see is that you're putting index-offset entries into your `data` (notice the `j+x` pattern):

```
(buf[j+8] << 24) | (buf[j+9] << 16) | (buf[j+10] << 8) | (buf[j+11])
```

while printing non-offset entires:

```
slog(0, SLOG_DEBUG, "test:%X%X%X%X", buf[8], buf[9], buf[10], buf[11])
```

Technically, data you're printing and putting into the float is only the same for `i==0`.

Comment: Yes this is deliberate.  For testing I am only trying to print one of a possible 4 floats in buf[].